# Karma Jasmine PhantomJS- PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms

Tags: phantomjs, karma-jasmine

In Package JSON, I have tried many different versions of karma-phantomjs-launcher, phantomjs, including phantomjs-prebuilt.

**Current Package JSON**
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.20"
  }

In all cases I get "PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms"  It tries twice, then gives up.

I am on Windows 10, running from command line in WebStorm.  However, I get same errors in Visual Studio Code.

What is the problem? Karma starts, Karma finds files, PhantomJS starts, but does not capture.

I've seen suggestions to set localhost in hosts file and checking whether karma port 9876 is already in use.  Nothing seems to work.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From this thread https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/84

Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts` (if you're on Linux)

Add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to your host file and it works!

Comment: this solution is not fix the problem

Comment: worked for me and apparently 10 other users on the github issue tracker, but yeah it's not an universal solution ;)